# Unable to delete directory in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When i run project in **Android Studio 2.0** it shows the following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'. > Unable to delete
>   directory: XX\build\outputs\apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android studio terminal , go to your projects root directory and use command :

```
./gradlew clean
```

Hopefully this will work just in case if it won't,go manually and delete generated apks in output folder and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

On the mac / ubuntu, when you move projects, just deleting `build` folder does not help. Instead I checked ownership of folders and files and realised that android studio was expecting the ownership to me `myusername:staff` and the files were `root:staff`

I ran the cmd `chown -R myusername:staff *` and the build went thru fine.